# How to save output result in txt file with each image with yolo python

Tags: python, file, loops, save

i am using yolo - python to detect object from multiple images.
i need to loop through result (describe detected object) to write that result in multiple text files (same name with name of image).
Example: 1.jpg detected 1 car & 1 dog => 1.txt contain car & dog.

i tried create multiple text file with glob(input image folder)
i tried loop through text (describe detected object) but i can't write result of each image to each text file. Something wrong with loop.
Please check the code in bottom, part of cv2.putText.

```py
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time
import cv2
import os, os.path
import glob

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-y", "--yolo", required=True,
    help="base path to YOLO directory")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type=float, default=0.3,
    help="threshold when applyong non-maxima suppression")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

num = 1
text_path_list = []
def create_result_text(textDir = "input"):
    for i in glob.glob("input/*.jpg"):     
        f = open(i.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ] + ".txt", "w+")
        f.close()
    temp = os.listdir(textDir)
    for i in temp:
        if (i.endswith("txt")):
            text_path_list.append(i)

create_result_text()

print(text_path_list)
# load the COCO class labels our YOLO model was trained on
labelsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov3.txt"])
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")

# initialize a list of colors to represent each possible class label
np.random.seed(42)
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3),
    dtype="uint8")

# derive the paths to the YOLO weights and model configuration
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov3.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join([args["yolo"], "yolov3.cfg"])

# load our YOLO object detector trained on COCO dataset (80 classes)
print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)

# read input image   
imageDir = "input" #specify your path here
image_path_list = []
valid_image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff"] #specify your vald extensions here
valid_image_extensions = [item.lower() for item in valid_image_extensions]

for file in os.listdir(imageDir):
    extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if extension.lower() not in valid_image_extensions:
        continue
    image_path_list.append(os.path.join(imageDir, file))

# load input image and grab its spatial dimensions
for imagePath in image_path_list:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    (H, W) = image.shape[:2]

    # determine only the *output* layer names that we need from YOLO
    ln = net.getLayerNames()
    ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

    # construct a blob from the input image and then perform a forward
    # pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes and
    # associated probabilities
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
    swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    start = time.time()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
    end = time.time()

    # show timing information on YOLO
    print("[INFO] YOLO took {:.6f} seconds".format(end - start))

    # initialize our lists of detected bounding boxes, confidences, and
    # class IDs, respectively
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    classIDs = []

    # loop over each of the layer outputs
    for output in layerOutputs:
     # loop over each of the detections
        for detection in output:
            # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability) of
            # the current object detection
            scores = detection[5:]
            classID = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classID]

            # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
            # probability is greater than the minimum probability
            if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                # scale the bounding box coordinates back relative to the
                # size of the image, keeping in mind that YOLO actually
                # returns the center (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding
                # box followed by the boxes' width and height
                box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")

                # use the center (x, y)-coordinates to derive the top and
                # and left corner of the bounding box
                x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                y = int(centerY - (height / 2))

                # update our list of bounding box coordinates, confidences,
                # and class IDs
                boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                classIDs.append(classID)

    # apply non-maxima suppression to suppress weak, overlapping bounding
    # boxes
    idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, args["confidence"],
        args["threshold"])

    result_texts = []
    # ensure at least one detection exists
    if len(idxs) > 0:
        # loop over the indexes we are keeping
        for i in idxs.flatten():
            # extract the bounding box coordinates
            (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
            (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

            # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
            color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
            cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
               0.5, color, 2)
            result_texts.append(text)
            print(result_texts)
            for text in result_texts:
                np.savetxt("input/" + str(num) + ".txt", np.array(result_texts), fmt="%s")
                num += 1
```

i expect each of text to has name of object of each image
but all text have name of object of last image.

Comment: i think for loop in yolo can not realize when an Image already detected, so it overwrites in my last result.
Please help me, im newbie of python. yolo is on the internet

Comment: have you thought if using the current date and time as filename? That would be unique names  that won't be overwritten.